# WPF Styling child control based on parent command enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, label

I just want to make the `Label` inside my `Button` template look disabled. Scoured the Internet and this seems like a simple task, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandProcess}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Images\Cloud-Upload.png"/>

        <Label Content="Upload and Process" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Please select a record type for each file selected for processing"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

`EDIT:` (*full code after using the answer by RV1987*)

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandProcess}" x:Name="ProcessButton">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Images\Cloud-Upload.png"/>

        <Label Content="Upload and Process" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=ProcessButton}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=ProcessButton}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Please select a record type for each file selected for processing"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ElementName` instead. `RelativeSource = FindAncestor` won't work here since button does not lies in Visual Tree but instead its the sibling of StackPanel. Give `name to button` and use it in your binding using `ElementName` -

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandProcess}" x:Name="MyButton">
```

and in DataTrigger -

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=MyButton}"
             Value="False">
   .....
</DataTrigger>
```

`Visual Tree` structure for Label and Button is like this -

```
Label <--- StackPanel <--- StackPanel's Parent
Button <--- StackPanel's Parent
```

As it can be seen Button is the sibling of StackPanel and it lies nowehere in the Visual tree of Label that's why `FindAncestor` won't get you to `Button`.

Comment: Perfect thanks, had to add a "White" setter for True also but works great, thanks again